# How to remove hyphens of a text on a <Text> tag on React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I had started recently to study react native and I'm passing through a several problem on my application. I have a  tag that I need to pass a text, that's ok. But I can't let this text had hyphens on it, because it's focus on children. So, I need to remove any hyphen that is generated automatically for the  tag. Anybody here has passed from some situation like that?

```
<Text 
style={mixedGuideTextStyle}
font="madeWaffle">
"testetdgtsd sdfugkgfus wsefjkhksdhfsdh sjfkdhgdschsdk swedifuhskdichksh sdhcksdhjchds"
</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the text content of the `<Text>` element to be dynamically rendered so that any `'-'` character is removed.

A simple solution would be to render the text content of `<Text>` inside of an expression (ie via `{ }`), and use the [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method on the string to replace all `'-'` characters with an empty string like so:

```
<Text 
style={mixedGuideTextStyle}
font="madeWaffle">
{ "testetdgtsd-sdfugkgfus-wsefjkhksdhfsdh".replace(/-/gi, '') }
</Text>
```

This will cause the text element to render with this string content:

`testetdgtsd-sdfugkgfus-wsefjkhksdhfsdh`

Comment: Hey, men, thank you for the attention. But the real problem is that the Hyphens are being generated automatically, I don't pass the string with hyphen. So, if a I just replaced, then would't do any difference, because the string has no hyphen. Can you think in something else?

Comment: @GlautonSantos you're welcome - can you show how the string is being supplied? I can update my answer to suit that :)

Comment: It's comming from a server, but those words that I put into the <Text> how example works fine too, any string example that you use will gonna work, it's just that some words are too large and instead of break a line, it's beeing added a hyphen.

Comment: Is the string content and JSX being rendered directly on the server? Am I correct that the string content passed to `<Text>` is not passed from component state?

Comment: Dacre, I think I found the problem. On my country we use the hyphen to keep a word on another line when ends the actual line. So, as I'm seeing on the code, someone did a function to do this rule of my language, thats why the hyphen was appearing automatically. I will gonna see what I can do to remove this function here. Thank you for the help!!

Comment: You're welcome - glad I could help, message me if there's anything else I can assist with :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the global flag:

```
var str="185-51-671";
var newStr = str.replace(/-/g, "");
```

You could aslo

```
str.split('-').join('');
```

this should also work.

You're good to go!

Comment: Hello Akshay, thank you for the commentary. But unfortunately the real problem is that the hyphen is being generated automatically, so, If I just replace or use the split and join, it would change only the string inside the <Text>, that has no hyphens. I wonder know how to remove the hyphens after the it being generated automatically or just made it unable that my tag would have it.

Comment: how is it possible that the hyphens are generated automatically.

Comment: Akshay, on my country we use the hyphen to keep a word on another line when ends the actual line. So, as I'm seeing on the code, someone did a function to do this rule of my language, thats why the hyphen was appearing automatically. That's why it was so anormal, but I think I know how to solve the problem now. Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own component that does that for you applying the replace function pointed by @Akshay Mulgavkar

```
function NoHyphensText({ children }) {
  return (
          <Text 
            style={mixedGuideTextStyle}
            font="madeWaffle">
              {children.replace(/-/gi, ' ')}
          </Text>
  );
}
```

And then just use it like this

```
<NoHyphensText>Render-this-whithout-hyphens</NoHyphensText>
```